# generated empty [i] in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, indices

I want to create an empty set up to the value n entered by the user and assign the values in the for loop into this set. But for this, it is necessary to create as many for loops as the user inputs, it is not possible to do this. How can I do it?

The code below works correctly, but I manually enter the value n=4. Again I'm creating j indices manually. I want to get this value of n from the user and create j indices as much as this value.

```
def result():
    for j in combinations(lastList, 4):
        if  j[0] + j[1] + j[2] + j[3] == sum:
            print (j[0] , j[1] , j[2] , j[3])
```

Comment: What is `sum`, where do you define it?

Comment: thank you to those who replied, @ Barmar and @ gilf0yle I tried and my codes worked, I can't give a feedback because my points isn't enough for it. Again thanks you..

Comment: Glad that my answer did help you. consider accepting the solution you have that privilege.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sum()` function to add all the elements of a sequence, so you don't have to write the indexes explicitly.

```
def result(n, s):
    for j in combinations(lastList, n):
        if sum(j) == s:
            print(*j)
```

BTW, don't use `sum` as a variable name, since it's the name of a built-in function.

Comment: Thank you for you interest. I tried and it worked. I won't use it as a variable, sum()

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got the point, but maybe you want to do something like

```
def result(num: int, sum_: int) -> None:
    for a, b, c, d in combinations(lastList, num):
        if  a + b + c + d == sum_:
            print (a, b, c, d)
```

Comment: @MustafaTokat Please vote if you find that an answer is useful.

Comment: sum(interated tuple) would have been more readable great answer though.

Answer (score 1):

this answer is according to my interpretation of the questions might be wrong. but !!works!!

```
def result():
    expected_sum=int(input("User please enter required sum"))
    n=int(input("User please enter the number"))
    for j in combinations(lastList, n):
        if   sum(j)== expected_sum:
            print (j)
```

Comment: Thank you for you interest. I tried and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do the following with the input abilities for the sum you want to achieve and the number you have.

```
def result(number, sum_goal):
     for list_item in combinations(lastList, number):
           if sum(list_item) == sum_goal:
                print('List of item is: ', list_item)
```

Then on the main program do the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   number = int(input("This is the number"))
   sum_goal = int(input("This is the sum"))
   result(number, sum_goal)
```

[image]

[image]